# Lambda implementation for OR expression concatenation

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new to lambda expressions; I am learning by implementing them. I have a question on how to convert a for-loop into a lambda expression.

`EnumHelper.GetEnumFromString` is a helper method that takes the string description and sends back the enum.

```
 [Flags]
    public enum Colors
    {
        [DescriptionAttribute("YL")]
        Yellow = 1,
        [DescriptionAttribute("RD")]
        Red = 2,
        [DescriptionAttribute("GR")]
        Green = 4
    }

 string colorStr = "GR,RD";
 List<Colors> clrs = colorStr.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(p => EnumHelper.GetEnumFromString<Colors>(p)).ToList();
 Colors currentValidColors = Colors.Green;

    for (int i = 0; i < clrs .Count; i++)
    {
         if (i == 0)
              currentValidColors = clrs [i];
          else
              currentValidColors = currentValidColors | clrs [i];
    }
```

Comment: if i understood you right, you are asking for a linq solution (lambda expressions are just the way to create anonymous functions)

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Are you having a problem with the current code, or you want different implementation of the current code? For converting string descriptions to Enums you can use Enum.Parse() or Enum.TryParse()

Comment: You'll want to look into the `aggregate` extension method to aggregate all of the `Colors` into a single `Colors`.  On a side note, `Colors` actually represents a single Color, so you should rename it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are thinking of? ForEach extension method is only available for generic lists.

```
Colors currentValidColors = 0;
colorStr.Split(new char[] { ',' })
.Select(p => EnumHelper.GetEnumFromString<Colors>(p))
.ToList()
.ForEach(c => currentValidColors |= c);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for... but I heard that ForEach does not return anything back. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't return anything. It was typo on my part sorry. Fixed it now. The value of currentValidColors is set within the |= c statement.

Answer (score 2):

This way may be conciser:

```
Colors currentValidColors = 
    colorStr.Split(',')
            .Select(EnumHelper.GetEnumFromString<Colors>)
            .Aggregate((a, b) => a | b);
```